# operational error: database is locked

Tags: python, flask

So I know this problem is not new in flask, and people have already asked it before. However I am still facing a problem while executing my database commands in bash as I am new to python.
This is what i did

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite.connect('/home/pjbardolia/mysite/tweet_count.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("create table count_twitter (count_id integer primary key autoincrement ,count_present integer not null,last_tweet not null)")

c.execute(insert into count_twitter values('',10,10))
```

however after executing insert statement I am getting operational error: database is locked.
Can someone tellme in simple terms what does this error means? and how to solve it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to check but is the last line in your code actually:
`c.execute("insert into count_twitter values('',10,10)")`?

The  [SQLite doc page](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked) for that error gives plenty of guidance. One thing to watch in Flask is going from dev mode (using "app.run()") to production mode (in a WSGI server) you are moving from single to multiple threads which might cause problems with SQLite and require extra concurrency handling.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is what this error means:

> SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can't support a
>   high level of concurrency. OperationalError: database is locked errors
>   indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than
>   sqlite can handle in default configuration. This error means that one
>   thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and
>   another thread timed out waiting for the lock the be released.
>
> Python's SQLite wrapper has a default timeout value that determines
>   how long the second thread is allowed to wait on the lock before it
>   times out and raises the OperationalError: database is locked error.
>
> If you're getting this error, you can solve it by:
>
> Switching to another database backend. At a certain point SQLite
>   becomes too "lite" for real-world applications, and these sorts of
>   concurrency errors indicate you've reached that point.
>
> Rewriting your code to reduce concurrency and ensure that database
>   transactions are short-lived.
>
> Increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database
>   option.

Probably you have another connection in your code that is not closed or not committed and this cause this error. Basically trying to do second `execute` when it is already locked by the another one. If you really want to have your concurrent transactions you need to have a [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system).

Comment: isnt there a journal mode wal that covers this?

Comment: This is what I was experiencing. I had my flask shell running in the background.

Comment: I would like to add that there are performance optimizations that you can look into in these scenarios and they may satisfy your needs. As @PirateApp mentioned there is journal mode=WAL. Please consult here:

https://sqlite.org/wal.html

And here:

https://phiresky.github.io/blog/2020/sqlite-performance-tuning/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found killing all Python processes solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you commit the other connections by using con.commit()

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used to manage concurrency.  I was hitting one DB from 270 processes.  Just increasing SQLite's timeout didn't help, but this approach where you just wait without attempting to connect for a while seemed to work.  The number of attempts (50) and wait period (10-30 seconds) could be adjusted.  I was collecting results from long running analyses, so 10-30 seconds was fine, but maybe 1-3 would have worked.

```py
import random
import sqlite3

def do_query(path, q, args=None, commit=False):
    """
    do_query - Run a SQLite query, waiting for DB in necessary

    Args:
        path (str): path to DB file
        q (str): SQL query
        args (list): values for `?` placeholders in q
        commit (bool): whether or not to commit after running query
    Returns:
        list of lists: fetchall() for the query
    """
    if args is None:
        args = []
    for attempt in range(50):
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect(path)
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(q, args)
            ans = cur.fetchall()
            if commit:
                con.commit()
            cur.close()
            con.close()
            del cur
            del con
            return ans
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            time.sleep(random.randint(10, 30))
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted a row from the DBBrowser for sqlite GUI tool then I posted the form data and I got the same error.

I closely look at the GUI and there is "Write Changes" tab which was active, means after i delete, i had to click on this. I click on that and problem was solved. sqllite3 is light but not that light

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using threads in my flask app, I tried almost everything (Checking if the Syntax of ORM command is right etc.), but all of these tries didn't solve my issue.

The last thing I did was to change the database from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was viewing the database from a Database Viewer and simultaneously tried to update the database from my browser flask site and it threw this error. Closing the database from the database viewer solved the issue for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30798710)