# sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked - How to avoid this?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using an open source piece of python code that basically pulls in a location of an entity and saves these details to a DB in real time. lets call it scanner the scanner program. DB file it saves it to is a sqlite file: db.sqlite.

As this is happening my piece of code in question is searching the db file every 45 seconds performing a select statement to find a certain value. This will work a couple of times but after running for a couple of minutes concurrently with the scanner program they run into a DB lock error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

So what can I do to my code to ensure this lock does not happen. I cannot change how the scanner program accesses the DB. Only my program.

Any help here would be great. I've seen timeouts mentioned along with threading but I am not sure on either.

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import sqlite3
    import time
    import json

    import tweepy

    def get_api(cfg):
      auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cfg['consumer_key'], cfg['consumer_secret'])
      auth.set_access_token(cfg['access_token'], cfg['access_token_secret'])
      return tweepy.API(auth)


      # Fill in the values noted in previous step here
    cfg = { 
        "consumer_key"        : "X",
        "consumer_secret"     : "X",
        "access_token"        : "X",
        "access_token_secret" : "X" 
        }



    with open('locales/pokemon.en.json') as f:
        pokemon_names = json.load(f)




    currentid = 1
    pokemonid = 96 #test



    while 1==1:

        conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
        print "Opened database successfully";

        print "Scanning DB....";
        time.sleep(1)
        cur = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM sightings WHERE pokemon_id = ? and id > ?", (pokemonid, currentid))
        row = cur.fetchone()

        if row is None:
            print "No Pokemon Found \n "
            time.sleep(1)


        while row is not None:

            #get pokemon name
            name = pokemon_names[str(pokemonid)]


            #create expiry time
            datestr = datetime.fromtimestamp(row[3])
            dateoutput = datestr.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

            #create location
            location = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/%s,%s" % (row[5], row[6]) 

            #inform user
            print "%s found! - Building tweet! \n" % (name)
            time.sleep(1)

            #create tweet
            buildtweet = "a wild %s spawned in #Dublin - It will expire at %s. %s #PokemonGo \n "%(name, dateoutput, location)
            #print tweet


            #log
            print buildtweet
            currentid = row[0]
            time.sleep(1)


            #send tweet
            api = get_api(cfg)
            tweet = buildtweet
            try:
                status = api.update_status(status=tweet)
                print "sent!"
            except:
                pass
                print "this tweet failed  \n"
            time.sleep(30)

            row = cur.fetchone()

        cur.close()
        conn.close()


        print "Waiting..... \n "
        time.sleep(45)

    conn.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [operational error: database is locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862809/operational-error-database-is-locked)

Comment: This doesn't help my issue I'm afraid.

Comment: It really does.  You either need to rewrite so you're not holding the connections open (with subsequent risk of timeouts and the DB being locked), or use another database.   As an example, I'd close the database cursor and connection before waiting 30s.  You only need the connection when you're carrying out transactions.