# Make peewee model JSON serializable?

Tags: python, json, serialization, flask, peewee

I have been working on a small web app and I decided it would be a good idea if I used email verification. Well, when I attempted to add email verification I sort of broke my code... I keep getting a traceback telling me the following:

> TypeError: <'peewee.CharField object at 0x7f46c6a7ba50> is not JSON serializable

I have come to the conclusion that I need to make my users model JSON serializable but I am not 100% sure that's what I need to do. Even if I am right, I wouldn't know how to do that.

Here is my user model:

```
class User(UserMixin, Model):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField(max_length=20)
    email = CharField(unique=True)
    confirmed = BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmed_on = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    joined_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        database = db
        order_by = ('-joined_at',)

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username, email, password, confirmed):
        try:
            with db.transaction():
            cls.create(
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=generate_password_hash(password),
                confirmed=False)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValueError("User already exists")
```

as far as email verification goes here is what I tried:

```
def generate_serializer(secret_key=None):
    return URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])


def generate_activation_url(user):
    serializer = generate_serializer()
    token = serializer.dumps(user.username)
    return url_for('activate_user', token=token, _external=True)

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    form = forms.RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        models.User.create_user(
            username=form.username.data,
            email=form.email.data,
            password=form.password.data,
            confirmed=False
        )
    token = generate_activation_url(models.User)
    msg =Message(render_template('activation_email.html', token=token),
                                  recipients=[models.User.email])
    mail.send(msg)

    return render_template('activate.html', user=models.User)
return render_template('index.html', form=form)


@app.route('/activate/<token>')
def activate_user(token, expiration=3600):
    serializer = generate_serializer()
    try:
        serializer.loads(token, salt=app.config[
                                   'SECRET_KEY'], max_age=expiration)
    except (BadSignature, SignatureExpired):
        abort(404)

    models.User.confirmed = True
    flash('User activated')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: please, make [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question

Comment: it seems like [`Field`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#fields) objects like `CharField` have `db_value` fields, try to serialize them with `serializer.dumps(user.username.db_value)`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I updated the code like so:
`token = serializer.dumps(user.username.db_value)` and now I get this traceback:
`TypeError: <bound method CharField.db_value of <peewee.CharField object at 0x7effb44b5a50>> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: suppose it should be `serializer.dumps(user.username.db_value())`

Comment: Oops sorry silly mistake :/

Comment: Okay I think that worked because it is getting s completely different error now :) Thank you very much

Comment: which one? you can (and probably should) post different question

Comment: `OperationalError: Database is locked`

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862809/operational-error-database-is-locked

Comment: Thank you again :)