# Why I can not insert more than 165 rows into a sqlite database asynchronously?

Tags: python, sqlite, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I was playing around with [aiosqlite](https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/stable/api.html). I wrote this code to insert 1000 rows into a database:

```
import asyncio
import aiosqlite
import inspect
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
counter = 1


async def write_to_db(number):
    global counter
    db = await aiosqlite.connect('test_database.db')

    command = '''
                INSERT INTO "main"."person"
                ("first_name", "last_name", "age")
                VALUES ('sample_first_name', 'sample_last_name', 21);
              '''
    print(f'croutine number {number + 1} connected to the database.')
    await db.execute(command)
    print(f'before commit in coroutine number: {number + 1}')
    # await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await db.commit()
    print(f'commit done in coroutine number: {number + 1}')
    await db.close()
    print('rows inserted so far:', counter)
    counter += 1


async def insert_many_times():
    await asyncio.gather(
        *[write_to_db(number) for number in range(1000)])


async def initialize_db():
    async with aiosqlite.connect('test_database.db') as db2:
        await db2.execute(
            '''
                CREATE TABLE "person" (
                "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
                "first_name"    TEXT NOT NULL,
                "last_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
                "age"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
                );
            '''
        )
        await db2.commit()
    await insert_many_times()


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(initialize_db())
```

This code can insert about 165 rows into the database and after that I get the database lock error:

```
croutine number 1 connected to the database.
croutine number 2 connected to the database.
croutine number 3 connected to the database.

...

croutine number 517 connected to the database.
croutine number 518 connected to the database.
croutine number 519 connected to the database.

...

croutine number 998 connected to the database.
croutine number 999 connected to the database.
croutine number 1000 connected to the database.
before commit in coroutine number: 2
commit done in coroutine number: 2
rows inserted so far: 1
before commit in coroutine number: 855
commit done in coroutine number: 855
rows inserted so far: 2
before commit in coroutine number: 907
commit done in coroutine number: 907
rows inserted so far: 3

...

before commit in coroutine number: 285
commit done in coroutine number: 285
rows inserted so far: 163
before commit in coroutine number: 990
commit done in coroutine number: 990
rows inserted so far: 164
before commit in coroutine number: 387
commit done in coroutine number: 387
rows inserted so far: 165
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ali Safapour\Desktop\1\1\test.py", line 54, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(initialize_db())
  File "C:\Users\Ali Safapour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete

...

  File "C:\Users\Ali Safapour\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiosqlite\core.py", line 102, in run
    result = function()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

As you can see the coroutines has been scheduled in the event loop in order. Because at first, we got the database object in the coroutine number 1, after that we got it in the coroutine number 2 immediately and so on. After gettig database object in all the coroutines from `aiosqlite.connect('test_database.db')`, we can not see special order in executing sql commands. This is the nature of asyncio: if we need to wait for I/O, we can do something else. If the result is ready, then we can continue.
My questions are:

1. For example in coroutine number 1 which is the first scheduled coroutine in the event loop, why Python did not continue to the rest of coroutine (i.e: running `db.execute(command)`) in between of connecting other coroutines to the database? obviously the required time for awaiting on `db.execute(command)` and `db.commit()` in the first coroutines, is less than awaiting on the coroutine number 1000 (last coroutine that connects to the databse) to get the database object.
2. As you can see, Python stopped inserting the rows into the database when 165 rows already inserted. If something like this is going to happen (no matter how many times you execute this code, always about 160 rows are going to be inserted), why 165 rows inserted already and there was no problem?
3. There is an `await asyncio.sleep(2)` in the `write_to_db` coroutine. If you uncomment that, you will see only one or two record will be inserted into the database. Why is that so? Can somebody exactly explain that how coroutines are scheduled in the event loop in this example and what is the order of them?

I don't need just a quick fix for this code to work, because I can do it myself. I need someone to explain what is happening exactly in the event loop and why this problem happens.

Comment: Each coroutine opens a new database connection, but they are never closed.

Comment: Btw. do you need to have 1000 connections open at the same time ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I added await db.close() after await db.commit(). The problem still persists. I don't think having 1000 open connections at the same time is a problem. I could open only one connection but I can open as many connections as I want because Sqlite does not have a problem with the number of connections as long as you don't write on the same DB concurrently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [operational error: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862809/operational-error-database-is-locked)

Comment: "*why Python did not continue to the rest of coroutine*" "*Can somebody exactly explain that how coroutines are scheduled in the event loop in this example and what is the order of them?*" Welcome to asynchronous programming; processing order is not guaranteed. "*Python stopped inserting the rows into the database when 165 rows already inserted*" It isn't the number of inserted 165 rows, it's the number of simultaneous insert attempts happening. 165 finished means there's 835 still trying to get an exclusive lock.

Comment: @Schwern I know that processing order is not guaranteed. When coroutine number one connects to the database, db.execute(command) in the coroutine number one can be registered to be executed in the event loop before coroutine number 1000 register its database connector to the event loop. I said "order of them" because coroutines connected to the database in order. Actually, 165 is the number of inserted rows. I opened the database file and there were 165 rows in there.

Comment: @AliSafapour I'm saying 165 isn't significant, it's the 835 of remaining simultaneous connections all trying to insert at the same time. The coroutines connected quickly and in order because that's a relatively simple and non-locking operation which will take roughly the same amount of time for each. Executing an insert is more costly and can lock; once locked it's up to SQLite in what order the inserts are executed.

Comment: @AliSafapour See https://phiresky.github.io/blog/2020/sqlite-performance-tuning/ for tips on tuning SQLite to handle more throughput.

Comment: @Schwern In an async program, everything is done with one thread. How all other 835 connections are trying to insert at the same time if there is only one thread?

Comment: @Schwern Also note that 165 is not a constant number. If you run the code multiple times, you will get different results. Thus, it has nothing to do with the SQLite throughput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're gaining nothing from having 1000 connections. Iterating over 1 connection 1000 times is much, much, much faster.

The main advantage of aiosqlite is that it won't block other coroutines while waiting for its queries to execute. Talking to SQLite is I/O, aiosqlite gives you asyncio for SQLite queries.

A SQL database server (PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS SQL, etc...) runs in a separate process, possibly on a different machine, probably multi-threaded. In that case it *might* make sense to open multiple connections (not 1000); the SQL server can probably handle multiple queries simultaneously, and while that's happening Python can be preparing and executing more. This is the value of asynchronous I/O; while one coroutine is waiting for the SQL server, the other coroutines can proceed. Sending a query to a SQL server is I/O.

But SQLite is not a server. SQLite runs in the same thread as the Python code. If you have 1000 coroutines with 1000 connections doing 1000 queries at the same time they're all competing with the SQLite coroutine to do the work. It's all going to be linear, except now you have the overhead of managing 1000 coroutines with 1000 connections all trying to get an exclusive lock on the same table at the same time. There's a lot of overhead swapping between 1000 coroutines.

Instead, use one connection and run it in a loop. This is far, far faster. We can make it even faster by waiting until all inserts are done before committing; writing to disk is expensive.

```
async def insert_many_times():
    counter = 1
    async with aiosqlite.connect('test_database.db') as db:
      for number in range(1000):
        command = '''
                    INSERT INTO "main"."person"
                    ("first_name", "last_name", "age")
                    VALUES ('sample_first_name', 'sample_last_name', 21);
                  '''
        print(f'coroutine number {number + 1} connected to the database.')
        await db.execute(command)
        print('rows inserted so far:', counter)
        counter += 1
      await db.commit()
```

You can [tune the connection](https://phiresky.github.io/blog/2020/sqlite-performance-tuning/) if necessary.

---

The coroutines are all running in one thread, why aren't they executing in order? Because they're doing file operations.

When you insert and commit in SQLite, it has to do [a bunch of complicated locking and file operations](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html). Let's look at a simple example which illustrates the same behavior: 10 coroutines all opening a file and writing to it.

```
import asyncio
from aiofile import async_open

async def main():
  await asyncio.gather(
    *[write_to_file(number) for number in range(10)]
  )

async def write_to_file(number):
  print(f'{ number + 1 }: running')
  async with async_open(f'/tmp/hello{number}.txt', 'w') as afp:
    print(f'{ number + 1 }: opened file')
    await afp.write(f'Hello {number} world')
    print(f'{ number + 1 }: wrote to file')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When we run this, they all begin in order, but they open and write out of order.

```
1: running
2: running
3: running
4: running
5: running
6: running
7: running
8: running
9: running
10: running
1: opened file
3: opened file
2: opened file
4: opened file
5: opened file
8: opened file
7: opened file
6: opened file
10: opened file
9: opened file
1: wrote to file
3: wrote to file
2: wrote to file
4: wrote to file
5: wrote to file
8: wrote to file
6: wrote to file
10: wrote to file
7: wrote to file
9: wrote to file
```

Why?

Because doing I/O takes time. When a coroutine opens or writes a file it has to ask the operating system and then wait for it to be done (known as "blocking"). Instead of waiting, Python asyncio runs another coroutine and eventually gets back to checking the ones which are blocking. While all the coroutines are running in a single thread, the order in which their file operations complete is ***up to the operating system***.

Inserting and committing in SQLite is the same basic issue. While the coroutines and SQLite are all running in a single thread, each commit has to get locks and write to the disk. How long this takes and who gets the lock next is up to the operating system and SQLite's code for resolving lock contention.

---

With that in mind, let's answer the individual questions.

> *For example in coroutine number 1 which is the first scheduled coroutine in the event loop, why Python did not continue to the rest of coroutine (i.e: running db.execute(command)) in between of connecting other coroutines to the database?*

Probably because connecting doesn't do much.

---

> *As you can see, Python stopped inserting the rows into the database when 165 rows already inserted. If something like this is going to happen (no matter how many times you execute this code, always about 160 rows are going to be inserted), why 165 rows inserted already and there was no problem?*

Each insert/commit has to get an exclusive lock ([gory details here](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)). While it has the lock, nobody else can insert/commit. The default timeout waiting for a lock is 5 seconds. In your case, 165 rows get inserted before a connection times out waiting for a lock.

I get about 400. If I increase the timeout to 10 seconds I get about 450 because the program gets incredibly slow with hundreds of coroutines.

[From the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#sqlite-notes)...

> SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can’t support a high level of concurrency. OperationalError: database is locked errors indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than sqlite can handle in default configuration. ***This error means that one thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and another thread timed out waiting for the lock the be released.***

Replace "thread" with "coroutine".

---

> *There is an await asyncio.sleep(2) in the write_to_db coroutine. If you uncomment that, you will see only one or two record will be inserted into the database. Why is that so? Can somebody exactly explain that how coroutines are scheduled in the event loop in this example and what is the order of them?*

N coroutines all try to get the lock.

A coroutine gets the lock, waits 2 seconds, commits, and releases the lock. Meanwhile, the other coroutines are waiting.

2 seconds have passed.

A coroutine gets the lock, waits 2 seconds, commits, and releases the lock. Meanwhile, the other coroutines are waiting.

4 seconds have passed.

A coroutine gets the lock, and begins waiting for 2 seconds. After 1 second of waiting 5 seconds have passed and one of the waiting coroutines times out.

Comment: Thank you. It was very a very good explanation but I'm still confused. For my first question, you said, "Probably because connecting doesn't do much". Does it mean connecting to the database 1000 times take less time than executing a single SQL query? For testing this hypothesis, can you change the aiosqlite source code to make the connection take longer? If connecting to the database is not time-consuming, why they've even implemented it as a coroutine?

Comment: In the definition of the Connection class which exists in the core.py file of the aiosqlite, they've defined the __await__ method. I added a time.sleep(2) and now, each coroutine connects to the database with a 2 seconds delay. Yet, I cannot see db.execute running while the other coroutines are connecting to the database.

Comment: @AliSafapour 1) Each coroutine sleeps 2s before yielding the event loop, probably because it's before the `return self._connect().__await__()` (I don't know asyncio well). With 1000 coroutines that is 33 minutes. Reduce your coroutines to something manageable like 10 and add a print just before/after the sleep to see. 2) Instead, add a sleep just before `sqlite3.connect` (with prints before and after) and you'll see it waits for the first connection (which is initialize_db) and the write_to_db's connect in parallel. [Demo](https://gist.github.com/schwern/81c3d00751543fb4addf2fe504708ace)

Comment: @AliSafapour Add a random sleep before `sqlite3.connect` like `random.randrange(1, 10)/100` and watch some execute while some connect. Executing an insert is just so much more expensive than connecting.

Comment: Yes, I can see some coroutines execute while others connect when I added a random `time.sleep` before `sqlite3.connect`. But there are three questions: 1) Why this number should be random? (I tested it with a constant number and it didn't work). 2) Why putting `time.sleep` in the `__await__` method that I suggested first, did not work? 3) We are playing in an async environment. Isn't it better to put `asyncio.sleep` somewhere instead of `time.sleep`? Using `asyncio.sleep` seems more appropriate since we want to make a delay in connection time not to make a delay in preparation time.

Comment: @AliSafapour 1) It answers your original first question, why do they all connect and then execute? Because connecting is really fast and takes the same amount of time for each coroutine. If we add a constant sleep to each one they all still take the same time to connect. If we instead add a small, *random* sleep to each connection we see some executing while some are still connecting. 2) I don't know asyncio well, but I believe the awaiting doesn't start until `__await__` returns. Or maybe it's because `time.sleep` is blocking the whole thread. 3) Maybe, try it and LMK what happens.

Comment: It occurred to me that blocking sleep must have an impact on a program that uses only one thread. If aiosqlite use only the program's one thread, then we would see some coroutines execute while others connect whether we use a constant or a random blocking sleep. Also, after putting a constant blocking sleep before sqlite3.connect, the program waits for that constant time and suddenly all of the coroutines connect. So, connecting is multi-threaded in aiosqlite. As a result, random sleep makes a difference while constant sleep does not. The situation is more complex now.

Comment: Now the question is how this multi-threaded connection affects the awaiting on aiosqlite.connect. I should probably stop thinking. Anyway, I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: @AliSafapour It isn't multi-threaded, it's a single thread swapping between coroutines; nothing actually runs simultaneously within the Python process. That's why having multiple aoisqlite connections doesn't make sense; SQLite runs in your Python process. With 1000 connections Puthon is swapping like crazy between them. All asyncio and aoisqlite do is prevent your Python code from waiting around for I/O to finish: file and network access which includes SQLite queries.

Comment: I just checked the Connection class. It inherits from `Thread` and has the `start` and `run` methods. When await happens on an instance of Connection class, the `__await__` method is called and inside this method, they've called `self.start` which does two things: 1) creates a new thread and 2) runs whatever there is inside the `run` function in the newly created thread. If there was only one thread, we wouldn't see the program wait for N seconds (not N times the number of coroutines), and then, coroutines connect all at the same time when there is a `time.sleep(N)` in the code.