# Microsoft Azure App services: cannot write to sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, azure, azure-web-app-service, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to deploy my flask app on Microsoft Azure. On the deployed site it can read the db fine, but whenever I try to write to the db, it gives: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked

My file structure inside the app folder is:

- templates
- app.py
- db.sqlite

However when i run it on my local, everything works fine. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is not more information for us to help fixing your issue, such as the necessary code and configuration for using SQLAlchemy with SQLite.

So I suggest that you can carefully refer to the some topics about SQLite locked file for writing.

1. [Database Locking Behavior / Concurrency](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#database-locking-behavior-concurrency)
2. The items `Client/Server Applications` and `High Concurrency` of the section `Situations Where A Client/Server RDBMS May Work Better` in the SQLite offical page [`Appropriate Uses For SQLite`](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Meanwhile, some existing SO threads may will help you.

1. [sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529820/sqlite3-operationalerror-database-is-locked)
2. [SQLAlchemy and SQLite: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895176/sqlalchemy-and-sqlite-database-is-locked)

Hope it helps. If you can update your description to post more helpful information, I will try to reproduce your issue and fix it, and then update my post.