# Not able to write into Sqlite3 db - Azure Web App

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, azure-web-app-service

I am pretty new to Python/Azure Web App/Sqlite; hence need your help with this issue that am facing.

I have a Python Flask App using SQL Alchemy ORM with a Sqlite3 db, running on my local system perfectly with all read/write operations. I pushed all of this to Github along with my sqlite db file. But once I deploy this as an Azure Web App using Github; the read functionalities are working fine but am not able to write into the database.

e.g. Am able to login to my app but am not able to register a new user with the Azure Web App.

Honestly, I do not even know where to check for any errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to understand your question, you should make it reproducible. Have you received any error message?

Comment: This is the error that am getting   OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked.                                                                                               
Though I dont have the DB open anywhere else.

Comment: I believe someone did talk about it in here. But there seems to be no solution to it or maybe not updated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58672193/microsoft-azure-app-services-cannot-write-to-sqlite-database